# Create new item if not already exist with Webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I need a post method in my REST-API, implemented with Webflux. Every user can only create one item. If there does already exist an item for the current user in the database, the method should throw an error (400 Bad Request). It should work like "createIfNotExist". How can I achieve this with Webflux?

I started with:

```java
@PostMapping
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Item>> create(@RequestBody CreateItemCommand command) {
        UUID userId = userPrincipalService.getUserPrincipal();
        return repository.findByUser(userId)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(new Item(userId, command)))
                .flatMap(repository::save)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
}
```

But this approach works more like "createOrUpdate".

Comment: Did you try throwing an exception?

Comment: Yes but did not work as I expected. I tried ".flatMap(__ -> Mono.error(new UsernameAlreadyExistsException()))" but this line always throws the exception.

Comment: I'd assume the repository should already return a Mono that either contains the result or the error so try mapping according to that in your final `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```java
@PostMapping
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Item>> create(@RequestBody CreateItemCommand command) {
        UUID userId = userPrincipalService.getUserPrincipal();
        return repository.countAllByUserId(userId)
                .filter(count -> count < 1)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Item create error")))
                .then(Mono.just(new Item(userId, command)))
                .flatMap(repository::save)
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok);

}
```

Also add global error handling. Example you can find here - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors